# How to change the class attributes of the instance of the SQLAlchemyAutoSchema

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-marshmallow

I have a flask_sqlalchemy model that I want to serialize its instance and a list of its instances using SQLAlchemyAutoSchema:

```
class TestModel(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    test_comments = relationship("TestCommentModel", backref=backref("test", lazy="joined"), 
        lazy="dynamic", foreign_keys="TestCommentModel.test_id")


    def find_by_id( ...  # 
    
    def find_all(...  #
```

```
class TestSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):

    test_comments = ma.Nested(TestCommentSchema, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        dump_only = ("id",)
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = False
```

To do so, I create two instances of the above class as below:

```
test_schema = TestSchema()
test_list_schema = TestSchema(many=True)

test = TestModel.find_by_id(test_id)
serialized_test = test_schema.dump(test)

tests = TestModel.find_all()
serialized_tests = {"tests": test_list_schema.dump(tests)}
```

So what is serialized_test? It is what I want and it looks like this:

```
{"id":1, "comments": ["id": 1, "id":2]}
```

And what is serialized_tests? It looks like this:

```
{"tests": [
    {"id":1, "comments": ["id": 1, "id":2]},
    {"id":2, "comments": ["id": 3, "id":4]},
    ]
}
```

But I do not need comments. I just need:

```
{"tests": [
    {"id":1},
    {"id":2},
    ]
}
```

How can I have this without having to redefine another TestSchema such as TestListSchema?

If I could do something like this it would be really helpful:

```
test_schema = TestSchema()
test_list_schema = TestSchema(many=True)}
test_list_schema = test_list_schema.pop(test_comment)  # Pseudo Code
```

What I am actually trying to do is to remove class attributes from the instance.

Any solution of how to do that?

Or if I could conditionally add attributes to the class

```
# Pseudo code
class TestSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):

    if not many:
        test_comments = ma.Nested(TestCommentSchema, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        dump_only = ("id",)
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = False
```

any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do the following:

```
test_list_schema = TestSchema(many=True, exclude=("test_comments",))  # Don't forget the comma
```